# Flipping a Coin Ten Times, Probability It's a 2 Headed Coin

Tags: probability, combinatorics, bayes-theorem

The question:

Assume you have 10 coins labeled 1, 2, 3, ..., 10. The probability of flipping a heads on the $i^{th}$ coin is $\frac{i}{10}$. You flip a coin, and it comes up heads. What is the probability the coin is a 2 headed coin.

If the question is just $\frac{1}{10}$ for each coin, I think it's just a straightforward application of Bayes Rule

$P(2H|H) = \frac{P(2H)P(H|2H)}{P(H)}$

But, I'm really not sure how to do this with with the varying probability.

Comment: what do you mean by a 2 headed coin ?

Comment: I think OP means the 10th coin, which has probability 1 of flipping heads

Comment: If so, it is poorly worded.  As an extreme case, perhaps the coin does still have a heads and a tails pictured, but is a magnet being flipped onto a magnetic surface such that the tails side is attracted to the surface while the heads side is repelled, giving the desired odds.  Would you still call that coin a "2-headed coin"?  (*inb4 magnets don't work like that: I was just trying to make a point*)

Comment: To me, "2 headed coin" means a coin which has an head on each side.

Comment: @rubik yes, but he never made any mention of any coins having that property.  Of course, the only coin which could have that property out of the ten is the tenth one, but it is not explicitly stated that the tenth coin is in fact two-sided.  The probably could be zero for all we know as it could be the case that none of the coins have a head on each side.

Comment: EDIT: The following comes from my misreading the question, sorry. <You need a prior to apply Bayes, surely. In particular, you need to declare some options: "The coin is two-headed", "The coin is normal", "The coin is two-tailsed", for instance. You also need to pick a probability distribution over them. Without choosing a prior, you can only report a likelihood ratio, not a degree of belief.>

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to realize that each coin has an equal probability of being chosen,
thus in $100$ trials, each coin is likely to be chosen $10$ times,

and total number of heads expected will be $(1+2+3+...+10) = 55$

Thus $P(C_{10}|H) = \frac{10}{55}$

Comment: The answer is essentially correct so I upvoted, but "each coin will be chosen $10$ times" is a misleading statement. It's simply the most likely outcome.

Comment: @kviiri: Thanks, I wrote "expected" in the second part of the sentence, but forgot  to add suitable words for the first part.

Answer (score 0):

true blue anil's answer is correct and a fuller explanation is that if $C_i$ is the event that the $i$th coin is selected and $H$ that a head shows after the flip then $$\mathbb P(C_i \mid H) = \dfrac{\mathbb P(C_i \cap H)}{\mathbb P(H)}= \dfrac{\mathbb P(H \mid C_i )\mathbb P(C_i)}{\sum_{j=1}^{10} \mathbb P(H \mid C_j )\mathbb P(C_j)} = \dfrac{\frac{i}{10}\times \frac1{10}}{\sum_{j=1}^{10} \frac{j}{10}\times \frac1{10}}= \dfrac{i}{\sum_{j=1}^{10} j} =\dfrac{i}{55}$$

and so for the double-headed coin you have $\mathbb P(C_{10} \mid H)=\dfrac{10}{55}=\dfrac{2}{11}$